Help with sequencing topics in undergrad stats course
For several years I sequenced my stats course so that estimation theory came before sampling theory. Seemed to make sense—you need a couple of estimators in hand to talk about their distributions. But I realize that I'd been including confidence intervals in the sampling section since I then had the tools to construct the probability statement behind the CIs. But interval estimation is just that, estimation, and logic would dictate the topic should be in with estimation. I quickly scanned a few texts to see how they handled it but none seemed satisfactory to me. So my question is: what is the best way to finesse this chicken and egg problem? If I put CIs in with estimation then I have to wave my arms in the air on the distributions of the estimators, which is not good from a pedagogic standpoint. If I leave them in the sampling section they seem out of place to me now and I'm uncomfortable with it. Any thoughts, ideas?

Welcome to CV, TonyK. I teach sampling distribution of the mean and hint at sampling distribution of the variance before motivating interval estimation & interval-based inference, and from there I proceed into hypothesis testing. Caveat: I am teaching graduate students who have already been exposed to at least one UG statistics course (for which I thank you! :).

Aside: I disagree that CIs are "just estimation"... by the same token test statistics are "just estimation" also… but there's inferential logic built into both CIs and tests in a way that there's not in point estimates like, say, $\bar{x}$.

You would likely be interested in how people are teaching these concepts and methods today.  Good resources (use them as search keys) are GAISE, CAUSE, the (open) J. of Stats Ed., and the AP stats program.  The advantage of such research is that will put you in contact with the ideas of people who study and practice pedagogy, not (just) statistics, and who often have obtained objective information about what works and what does not.

@Alexis: Thanks for weighing in. I can see how in a grad course that might work. I'm struggling with how to do it when folks don't know anything yet. Still, maybe I need to step back and rethink things.

@whuber. Thanks for the redirect, I will check it out. They sound really interesting. I will pursue.
